# Android ImageView Layout Issues

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

There very well may be a duplicate question, but I have yet to find it.  I am doing thing all programmatically, not using the xml. Basically what I am trying to do is to have an EditText appear below an image. I am using RelativeLayout with an ImageView and and EditText.

These are the parameters that I am setting up for the ImageView and EditText:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
editTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
editTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
editTextParams.width=500;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, editText.getId());
```

Which I have verified correctly places the EditText in the bottom right corner and the image above.  What I run into is if the picture it "too tall" then it covers the EditText.  I also tried using

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

and it stretches it over the EditText as well.

The full code that I am using is this

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
EditText editText = new EditText(this);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
editTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
editTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
editTextParams.width=500;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, editText.getId());

imageView.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
editText.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);
Bitmap image = getImage();
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
layout.addView(editText);
layout.addView(imageView);
```

Thanks. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Width of 500 is a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a LinearLayout and then add the two components in it (ImageVIew and EditText)

Here is what you should do;

- Set the orientation to vertical for the horizontal layout and width to whatever you need
- Set the with of both components to 0 and weights to 1 each

After that, you should have the two items one above the other;

I hope this helps

Comment: This has been the most helpful (sorry to everyone else) and has solved my original issue. The EditText now always appears below the picture. I am now running into the issue of different pictures (I am guessing based on the dimensions of the picture) are leaving me with a lot of white space between the actual border of the picture and the EditText, but you have gotten me well on my way. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is fix the imageview width and height. This way you can control the maximum size without the imaging going over the edit text.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(256, 256);
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't fix the issue. All it did was make the picture smaller but didn't fix the issue. See the screen shot above, which is the original, the picture still overlapped like that but was just shrunk.

Comment: hmm. Another thing to try is instead of adding the image above the edittext, try to add the edittext below the image. So change the LayoutParams to that of below. Instead of `imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, editText.getId());` use this
`editTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imageView.getId());` THen add the image first to the view then the edittext.

Answer (score 0):

Your editText has a vertical MATCH_PARENT. Shouldn't it be WRAP_CONTENT?

(I am not sure if this helps, but it might help, as the MATCH_PARENT contradicts your planned layout, and your screenshot indicates that the editText is vertically centered.)